# How does this nested for loop work?

Tags: c++

today my tutor showed me a code that I didn't quite understand. It is a code that is supposed to tell us what prime number n is. Here is the code..

```
int main()
{
    const int max = 3;
    int count = 0;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 2;; i++) {
        for (j = 2; j < i; j++)
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        if (i == j) {
            count++;
            if (count == max)
                break;
        }
    }
    cout << max << "st prime number is: " << i;
}
```

so basically what I don't  understand is how this nested for-loop works. When it comes to i=3 will the inner for-loop even increment?... or will it directly proceed to the statements below? How will this program prove us that 3 is a prime number when 3 == 2 is not true? Still this program tells us that 3 is a prime number.. :s

Comment: If you formatted the code properly it would be a lot easier to understand it.

Comment: Debugging by printing is gold here. Print stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) number is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself.

The inner loop generate all numbers from 2 to i - 1, if i is divisible by any number < i so it's not prime.

```
if (i == j)
```

If j in inner loop reached i , it means inner loop didn't break !
so i is prime number.

Let's try with i = 3,
inner loop

```
for(j = 2; j < 3; ++j)
    if(i % j == 0) // i divisible by j
        break;
```

This loop will not terminate (because of that break) because 3 not divisible by 2, 
and now j = 3,

```
if(j == i)
```

is true now , and 3 is prime.